# Find a word preceding a symbol set

Tags: regex, swift

How can I find a word that preceding to [`¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰`]. For ex.:

```
let myString = "Regular expressions¹ consist of constants, ² and operator symbols...³"
```

Please, provide a pattern to select characters from start of the target word to superscript:

```
"expressions¹", "constants, ²", "symbols...³"
```

& pattern to select only target word

```
"expressions", "constants", "symbols"
```

Comment: This is not a problem, however your _words_ before the superscript don't follow a pattern too well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match your examples.

Codepoints:

`\b\w+\W*[\x{B9}\x{B2}\x{B3}\x{2074}\x{2075}\x{2076}\x{2077}\x{2078}\x{2079}\x{2070}]+`

From Wikipedia:

> The most common superscript digits (1, 2, and 3) were in ISO-8859-1 and were therefore carried over into those positions in the Latin-1 range of Unicode. The rest were placed in a dedicated section of Unicode at U+2070 to U+209F.

**Update**:

To get separate blocks that start with words or non-words, you can just
exclude the superscript range from the non-word class.
The regex is longer and more redundant, but it works.

`(?:\b\w+[^\w\x{B9}\x{B2}\x{B3}\x{2074}\x{2075}\x{2076}\x{2077}\x{2078}\x{2079}\x{2070}]*|[^\w\x{B9}\x{B2}\x{B3}\x{2074}\x{2075}\x{2076}\x{2077}\x{2078}\x{2079}\x{2070}]+)[\x{B9}\x{B2}\x{B3}\x{2074}\x{2075}\x{2076}\x{2077}\x{2078}\x{2079}\x{2070}]+`

Formatted

```
 (?:
      \b 
      # Required - Words
      \w+ 
      # Optional - Not words, nor supersctipt
      [^\w\x{B9}\x{B2}\x{B3}\x{2074}\x{2075}\x{2076}\x{2077}\x{2078}\x{2079}\x{2070}]* 

   |  # or,

      # Required - Not words, nor supersctipt
      [^\w\x{B9}\x{B2}\x{B3}\x{2074}\x{2075}\x{2076}\x{2077}\x{2078}\x{2079}\x{2070}]+ 
 )
 # Required - Superscript
 [\x{B9}\x{B2}\x{B3}\x{2074}\x{2075}\x{2076}\x{2077}\x{2078}\x{2079}\x{2070}]+
```

Comment: maybe is better to use .unicodeScalars view directly, not .utf16 view. the most difficult part is define all valid subscript unicode scalar values.

Comment: @user3441734 - Don't know Unicode, but the regex engine doesn't care what the hex form is, it translates into the proper codepoint even if the source text is utf-8. There is no surrogate pairs to worry about.

Comment: try to imagine some Chinese text or something similar. unicode scalar is the internal String representation, so if you have a set of superscript characters, you can find corresponding  index in unicodeScalar view and rest is than simple ....

Comment: @user3441734 - I don't know _`swift`_ regex but what form its list of constructs is called `unicodeScalar view` ? How is it represented to the engine?

Comment: i don't think about regex (it is not a part of swift for now). you can use pure swift String functionality from standard swift library.

Comment: very useful info about superscript !

Comment: Don't want to ask like a new question. Please, can you show me how to edit this pattern to do next thing: If string contains next combination `"Word¹!"²` find them both — `Word¹`, `!"²`. In other words, modify search to stop, when finded superscript number before superscript number from we searching one.

Answer (score 1):

based on sin's or Caleb Kleveter's information

```
    let myString = " expressions¹ consist of 元機經中有關文字排版² and operator symbols³"
    let noteIdx = "\u{2070}\u{00b9}\u{00b2}\u{00b3}\u{2074}\u{2075}\u{2076}\u{2077}\u{2078}\u{2079}"

    let strs = myString.unicodeScalars.split { (s) -> Bool in
        noteIdx.unicodeScalars.contains{ $0 == s }
    }
    strs.forEach {
        print($0)
    }
    /* prints

     expressions
     consist of 元機經中有關文字排版
     and operator symbols

    */
```

this is just a torso, you can continue if you want

Comment: Thank you, but @sln 's answer is very good for me and I think, that regex is faster (is it?), but you show me a new way to do this. ))